# Font Awesome image not appearing for list element

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying change the list-style-image to a font awesome content code f2bd, however; when I use it only shows an empty square box.  The check mark appears, circle, and other images, but not that one.

CSS

```
li:before {
  content: "\f2bd"; /* FontAwesome Unicode */
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  /*display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -1.3em; /* same as padding-left set on li */
  width: 5.3em; /* same as padding-left set on li */*
}
```

HTML

```
    <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-19" tabindex="0" style="width: 252px; top: 96px; left: 13px; display: none;"><li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-20" tabindex="-1"><i class="fas" fa-user-circle=""></i><a>Bob</a></li><li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-21" tabindex="-1"><i class="fas" fa-user-circle=""></i><a>Cooler</a></li></ul>
```

Comment: Does FA work elsewhere in your app?

Comment: Yes it does, but for some reason it doesn't work here. I'll look more into it.

Comment: your code works fine here

Comment: @isherwood why editing like this? you included all the needed code to make his code working, why you assumed he's including fontawesome in his code? probably it's the issue

Comment: @isherwood ok sorry, I didn't see the approved edit

Comment: The issue was that the image was not present in the css that was made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check this sample:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style : normal;
  src : url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0");
  src : url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font- 
awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0") format("woff2"),
         url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0") format("woff"),
         url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font- awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0") format("truetype"),
         url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font- awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular") 
format("svg");
}

li:before {
  content: "\f2bd"; /* FontAwesome Unicode */
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  /*display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -1.3em; /* same as padding-left set on li */
  width: 5.3em; /* same as padding-left set on li */*
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-19" tabindex="0" style="width: 252px; top: 96px; left: 13px; ">
  <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-20" tabindex="-1">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>
    <a>Bob</a>
  </li>
  
  <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-21" tabindex="-1">
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>
    <a>Cooler</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I just needed the font-family part to be added and put the image info in the css.

Answer (score -1):

Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52459026/font-awesome-icons-not-showing-from-cheat-sheet-code/52459216#52459216)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style : normal;
  src : url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0");
  src : url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0") format("woff2"), url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0") format("woff"), url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font- awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0") format("truetype"),
     url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
}
```

Comment: if it's the same question we don't repeat the same answer

Comment: I don't understand. If the need is the same, what should we answer ? Shouldn't we point other topics where we already discussed about it, so the asker gains time ? I'm new here, so please tell me if there is a particular rule in stack overflow instead of throwing -1, it's more constructive for new users like me.

Comment: you should flag the question as duplicate if you think it's the same issue that need the same answer ... we should avoid duplicate question and duplicate answers